# Convert cakephp3 created modified datetime zone to pacific

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In debug kit i can see that the default timezone for my created and modified datetime is saved by default as UTC timezone. 
However i want it to be saved in pacific timezone.

How can i change this behavior in cakephp3. I've google the issue but can't find any lead that is why i'm posting it here.

Comment: [This link](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/timezone-user-configuration-at-cakephp/) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who have this problem in future. [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html) is how to do it.

In your application bootstrap.php change timezone at this line:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is the list of supported timezones.